# WhatsApp Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whatsapp

I was just wondering if there is a ruby gem for [Whatsapp](http://www.whatsapp.com) similar to what is available in [PHP](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI).

I searched on Google, but could not find one.

Comment: Not sure why it is closed, seems like a valid question to me. I'm also searching for the same thing.

Comment: +1 to seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: -1 "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It's a valid question for me too, I think you should reconsider the politics about `What topics can I ask about here?` and make this question validate, there are a lot of people asking for this

Comment: Hey, you can use  https://github.com/ignacio-chiazzo/whatsapp_sdk